# aws CodeDeploy vs aws Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, continuous-deployment, aws-code-deploy

I have use case in amazon cloud, i'm using fargate cluster and cloudformation.
I want to do continuous deployment i.e on new image upload trigger i want to update the cloudformation stack with this new image, also run this automated deployment when client wants using manual trigger.

What should i use for continuous deployment, aws code deploy or aws lambda.

aws CodeDeploy has a provider CloudFormation with limited option and less control i believe.

aws lambda has a great control over CloudFormation client through its boto api.

I also read somewhere that when you get some limitations in CodeDeploy or CodePipeline you can integrate lambda to get rid of this limitation. So why not use lambda in the first place for continuous deployment only.

I'm very convinced about aws lambda over aws CodeDeploy after doing some research, However, i'm open for comments and suggestions.

Comment: Hello, you have a(docker?) image that you want to upload to ECS and run within your fargate tasks when the image has been updated?

Comment: @MrkFldig yes it is a docker image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them to achieve perfect CI-CD implementation

If image gets uploaded the Lambda will be triggered and Lambda will be having your configurations and parameters
Using that it will call CodeDeploy to build your ECR images and It will get deployed to your Farget cluster

You can also achieve your second need using this implementation, manual trigger when client wants
In lambda you can trigger manualy passing parameters runtime

I hope this helps you